# Bootstrap: Accordion within accordion, displaying dynamic content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having troubles getting my bootstrap accordions to work. The content is all dynamically generated, and I'd like for accordions to be nested within a top level parent accordion - here is the markup:

```
...
foreach($xml->Continent as $continent) {
   echo "<div class='accordion-group'><div class='accordion-header'><a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'>".$continent['Name']."</a><span>".$continent['Status']."</span></div>";
    foreach($continent->Country as $country) {
       echo "<div class='accordion-body collapse in'><div class='accordion-inner'><div class='accordion-group'><div class='accordion-header'><a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'>".$country['Name']."</a><span>".$country['Status']."</span></div>";
       foreach($country->City as $city) {
         echo "<div class='accordion-body collapse in'><div class='accordion-inner'>".$city['Name']."<span>".$city['Status']."</span></div></div>";
       }
       echo "</div></div></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
...
```

Basically.. the Continents should all be collapsed at a default state. But once you click and expand a Continent, inside it will list out Countries. Those Countries should also expand out to display Cities, and stop there.

I came a cross a different method before, but it was very fragile code and depended greatly upon the markup, which I don't think is a good route if my content is being dynamically generated and the contents can vary from 1 to many. I really just need to the collapse functionality to work, and if that means creating a script that assigns specific ids, then that works too - I'm just curious as to what the best method would be.

Comment: Be sure your <div> tags are right. At first glance, I noticed a `echo "</div>";` outside of your `foreach()`. Just a hunch...

Comment: ah, sorry. that's my fault for not including all of the code. the beginning of that div is echo'd before the Continent foreach.

Comment: Ok... no problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok... the issues are as follows:

- Missing `data-parent` attribute - e.g. `data-parent="#accordion2"`
- Missing `href` attributes - e.g. `href="#collapseOne"`
- Missing `id`
  attributes - e.g. `id="collapseOne"`

It may not be 100% perfect, but [see my example] and check out [Twitter Bootstrap's "Collapse" documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse)

- Additional note:
  Make sure the class 'in' is only included on the cities (e.g. `class='accordion-body collapse in'`). This makes those nodes expanded at all times. Excluse the 'in' class for nodes you want initially collapsed (continents and countries).

Comment: This is great, thank you. However, with it being dynamically generated content, what's the best way to handle those id's? They will have to be different for each accordion grouping. I know I'll have to write a script in order to give each group a unique id, but I'm struggling at where to start.

Comment: You could name your ids like this: `collapse1` instead of `collapseOne`. Then, set an incrementing variable like, `$i = 1` before looping, and incrementing with `$i++` within the loop. Then, use the numeric variable in constructing the id string, `$collapse_id = "collapse".$i;`

So, it would be structured like this:

`$i = 1;
foreach($xml->Continent as $continent) {
  $collapse_id = "collapse".$i;
  echo "<div id='".$collapse_id."'>";
  // and so on...
  $i++;
}`

Comment: What about the issue between Continent and Country.. There can be multiple Countries inside a Continent. So if a Continent has an id of "collapse1" it's going to give any and all Countries nested within it an id of "collapse1" as well.

Comment: Okay, so simple fix for that. I adjusted the output so that the Countries are contained within a collapsible div that has the id. Now I just need to get the incrementing working.. currently only getting "collapse1" ids.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to repeat the process throughout all of your loops. Since $i has been assigned, you'll need to change the variable names to something other than $i. (e.g. $j, $k, etc.)